# sql error database on main page

Tags: mysql

any idea how to repair this error? I get this error on the main website page

```
DATABASE ERROR

 ************************


 SELECT SQL_CACHE cid, title_ AS title
 FROM ilance_categories
 WHERE cattype = 'product'
 AND visible = '1'
 AND level <= '1'
 ORDER BY sort ASC

 MySQL Error : Unknown column 'title_' in 'field list'
 Error Number : 1054
 Date : Aug 12, 2014, 11:33:15
 Script : http://www.redsquaretags.com/main.php
 Class : ilance_mysql
 Location : main
 Referrer : Not referred
 IP Address : 196.22.238.162
 ILance Version : 4.0.0
 Build : 8059
 SQL Version : 898
 MySQL Version : 5.5.37-cll
 Server Load : n/a
 ************************

 END DATABASE ERROR
```

Thank you, that's the only error I have thank you

Comment: Are you sure the column name is correct? Shouldn't it be just "title"? The error message refers to this, it might be a typo perhaps?

Comment: output of `SHOW COLUMNS FROM ilance_categories`?

Comment: cattype 

enum('service','product') 

NO 

MUL 

service